# Select from 2 tables, both using JOIN and connected by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join

It's hard to search anywhere on this subject... Basically, I'm selecting from two tables, each of the table has `JOIN` clauses. If I separate queries by each table, both work fine... Below looks logically correct to me.. But it gives me an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'catalogue.ID' in 'on clause'  0.000 sec
```

Is this query possible, and what am I missing here?

```
SELECT  `catalogue`.`ID`,`catalogue`.`Catalogue`,`catalogue`.`Artist`,`catalogue`.`Title`, `catalogue`.`Street_Date`,
        `label`.`label_name` as `label`,
        `format`.`format_name` as `Format`,
        `schedule`.designer,`schedule`.`MO`,

        `packtype`.`description` as `Package`,
        `manufacturer`.`description` as `Manufacturer`

        FROM `catalogue`, `manufacture`

        LEFT JOIN `schedule` ON (`schedule`.`cat_id` = `catalogue`.`ID`) 
        LEFT JOIN `label` ON (`catalogue`.`label` = `label`.`Lbl_ID`) 
        LEFT JOIN `format` ON (`catalogue`.`format` = `format`.`Fmt_ID`) 

        LEFT JOIN `packtype` ON `packtype`.`pack_id` = `manufacture`.`pack_id`
        LEFT JOIN `manufacturer` ON `manufacturer`.`man_id` = `manufacture`.`manuf`

    WHERE `catalogue`.`Street_Date`="2014-03-17" and  `manufacture`.`cat_id` = `catalogue`.`ID`

    ORDER BY  `catalogue`.`Catalogue`  asc LIMIT 1 , 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing `join` types, so this is one of the problem you get.  You can fix this by replacing the `,` with `cross join`:

```
    FROM `catalogue` cross join `manufacture`

    LEFT JOIN `schedule` ON (`schedule`.`cat_id` = `catalogue`.`ID`) 
    LEFT JOIN `label` ON (`catalogue`.`label` = `label`.`Lbl_ID`) 
    LEFT JOIN `format` ON (`catalogue`.`format` = `format`.`Fmt_ID`) 

    LEFT JOIN `packtype` ON `packtype`.`pack_id` = `manufacture`.`pack_id`
    LEFT JOIN `manufacturer` ON `manufacturer`.`man_id` = `manufacture`.`manuf`
```

However, it surprises me that there are no `join` conditions between these tables.

Oh, I see the condition in the `where`.  Yuck!

```
    FROM `catalogue`
    LEFT JOIN `manufacture` ON `manufacture`.`cat_id` = `catalogue`.`ID`

    LEFT JOIN `schedule` ON (`schedule`.`cat_id` = `catalogue`.`ID`) 
    LEFT JOIN `label` ON (`catalogue`.`label` = `label`.`Lbl_ID`) 
    LEFT JOIN `format` ON (`catalogue`.`format` = `format`.`Fmt_ID`) 

    LEFT JOIN `packtype` ON `packtype`.`pack_id` = `manufacture`.`pack_id`
    LEFT JOIN `manufacturer` ON `manufacturer`.`man_id` = `manufacture`.`manuf`
```

This problem is actually [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

The simple solution is:  NEVER use `,` in the `from` clause.  If you want a cross join, then use `cross join`.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Elen you don't want to use the old `JOIN` syntax. Even more so you definitely shouldn't mix the old syntax with the new. I would also recommend using aliasing to make your code a little easier to read.

Comment: Gordon Linoff and @Zane - that where condition why like a cry for help.. i tried diff scenarios.. thanks i'll test it on Monday!